# Collecting messages

Tags: azureservicebus, nservicebus, saga, rebus

I have a flow where some handler publish event. And every 100 events I would like to do some operation. Is there any clever way to achieve that? I know that I could write handler that is running on host that is single-thread so it consumes only one message at a time and prevent of handling more than 100 messages. But I would like to avoid creating separate host only for this one case. Do you have any ideas how to do it with Rebus?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any clever way to achieve that?

No, not really. Or, to be more precise: I think there's many ways to do something like that, and the different solutions would have different properties.

E.g. you can use a static `long` and `Interlocked.Increment(...)` to count messages and compare the return value to `% 100` to determine if it's time to trigger something.

Or you could insert rows into a database and then have a separate background timer that queries the database and does whatever needs to be done, when there's 100 rows in the table – and then it could either delete the rows or mark them as handled.

So... no built-in way in Rebus, but probably lots of creative ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect any particular solution from Rebus itself, but rather some message-pattern to handle that. I think that option with Interlocked.Increment might be complicated in terms of supporting retries.